# fusion-tables, help needed with getting latest data from a table and inserting it in maps code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Hi all trying to find the code to pull the latest co-ordinates from a google fusion table and insert it into the code below as the origin. (var origin1)

GOOGLE Fusion table setup;

```
   {
     "kind": "fusiontables#columnList",
     "totalItems": 15,
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 0,
       "name": "description",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 1,
       "name": "kind",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 2,
       "name": "name",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 3,
       "name": "placeId",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 4,
       "name": "info1",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 5,
       "name": "info2",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 6,
       "name": "info3",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 7,
       "name": "info4",
       "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 8,
       "name": "accuracy",
       "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 9,
       "name": "speed",
       "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 10,
       "name": "heading",
       "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 11,
       "name": "altitude",
       "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 12,
       "name": "altitudeAccuracy",
       "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 13,
       "name": "timestamp",
       "type": "NUMBER"
      },
      {
       "kind": "fusiontables#column",
       "columnId": 14,
       "name": "geometry",
       "type": "LOCATION"
      }
     ]
    }
```

and here is some of the data it keeps, i am trying to get the "LATEST" geometry coordinates and add that my map, to provide realtime updates.

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "description",
  "kind",
  "name",
  "placeId",
  "info1",
  "info2",
  "info3",
  "info4",
  "accuracy",
  "speed",
  "heading",
  "altitude",
  "altitudeAccuracy",
  "timestamp",
  "geometry"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "",
   "",
   "Location at Mon 14/05/2012 13:42:58",
   "",
   "resourceasstring",
   "",
   "",
   "",
   "65",
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   1.336966978085E12,
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
      144.9339931215855,
      -37.83169408321385,
      0.0
     ]
    }
   }
  ],
  [
   "",
   "",
   "Location at Mon 14/05/2012 19:20:11",
   "",
   "resourceasstring",
   "",
   "",
   "",
   "1414",
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   1.336987211753E12,
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
      145.2516605102396,
      -37.92732182161065,
      0.0
     ]
    }
   }
  ],
  [
   "",
   "",
   "Location at Mon 14/05/2012 19:40:12",
   "",
   "resourceasstring",
   "",
   "",
   "",
   "1414",
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   1.336988412041E12,
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
      145.3447657261889,
      -37.91152087158031,
      0.0
     ]
    }
   }
  ],
  [
   "",
   "",
   "Location at Tue 15/05/2012 09:41:57",
   "",
   "resourceasstring",
   "",
   "",
   "",
   "65",
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   NaN,
   1.337038917553E12,
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
      144.9339498133275,
      -37.8317148043096,
      0.0
     ]
    }
   }
  ],
```

This is the html/java code that display's the map;

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Google Maps API v3 Example: Distance Matrix</title>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <style>
          body {
            margin: 20px;
            font-family: courier, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
          }
          #map {
            height: 480px;
            width: 640px;
            border: solid thin #333;
            margin-top: 20px;
          }
        </style>

        <script>
        //Taken and adopted from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix
        //Need to make the fusion table part work next!!
          var map;
          var geocoder;
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          var markersArray = [];

//var origin1 is where i want it to pull the data from the fusion table.
          var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.83169408321385,144.9339931215855);
          var destinationA = 'glen iris, Australia';


          var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
          var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';

          function initialize() {
            var opts = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.83,144.93),
              zoom: 20,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opts);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          }

          function calculateDistances() {
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                origins: [origin1],
                destinations: [destinationA],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
              }, callback);
          }

          function callback(response, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
              alert('Error was: ' + status);
            } else {
              var origins = response.originAddresses;
              var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
              var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
              outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
              deleteOverlays();

              for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                addMarker(origins[i], false);
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                  addMarker(destinations[j], true);
                  outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
                      + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
                      + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
                }
              }
            }
          }

          function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
            var icon;
            if (isDestination) {
              icon = destinationIcon;
            } else {
              icon = originIcon;
            }
            geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: results[0].geometry.location,
                  icon: icon
                });
                markersArray.push(marker);
              } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
                  + status);
              }
            });
          }

          function deleteOverlays() {
            if (markersArray) {
              for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
              }
              markersArray.length = 0;
            }
          }

        </script>
      </head>
      <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="60">
      <body onload="initialize(), calculateDistances()">
        <div id="inputs">
          <pre class="prettyprint">
    This will automatically calculate distances on load and then will re-load every minute. hahaha...
    Really need to work out how to pull data from a fusion table as well.
          </pre>
          <p><button type="button" onclick="calculateDistances();">Force Re-Calculate
            distances</button></p>
        </div>
            <div id="outputDiv"></div>
        <div id="map"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

thx
matt.

Comment: What it the FusionTable you are trying to get this information from?

Comment: a google fusiontable! is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you provide the numeric or encrypted id of a public table that contains the data?  Or even a link to it.

Comment: sorry, here u go, https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=TABLE&containerId=gviz_canvas&q=select+col0%2C+col1%2C+col2%2C+col3%2C+col4%2C+col5%2C+col6%2C+col7%2C+col8%2C+col9%2C+col10%2C+col11%2C+col12%2C+col13%2C+col14+from+14zYUb4evjnmHKu3sRIFJK5Pv2IR0j0NyJy6qrxc

Comment: Table is: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=14zYUb4evjnmHKu3sRIFJK5Pv2IR0j0NyJy6qrxc; [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linktoA.html?lat=-37.787958&lng=144.844406&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20name,%20geometry%20FROM&tableid=14zYUb4evjnmHKu3sRIFJK5Pv2IR0j0NyJy6qrxc) is a page that displays all the data (but doesn't query for the latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of concept:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_latestData.html

Uses the FusionTables API v1.0 to query the table for the data; creates a native Google Maps API v3 marker for the "latest" location (the one with the greatest value in the timestamp column).

Note that if you have lots of markers or only markers you may want to modify the approach.